# Passing parameters from one SConstruct to another SConstruct using scons

Tags: python, scons

I have a C project built using SCons that links with a C library also built by Scons. Both the library and the project have there own SConstruct files. I read in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23898880/6198533) that you can call a SConstruct from another SConstruct in the same way as you would call a SConscript:

```
SConscript('folder/to/other/SConstruct')
```

Command line parameters provided to the top level SConstruct are automatically passed to the called SConstruct. But now I want to pass additional variables to the called SConstruct. I figured out that you can do this in the same way as you would do with SConscripts:

```
SConscript('folder/to/other/SConsctruct', exports='my_variable')
```

And then import them in the called SConstruct:

```
Import('my_variable')
```

The problem is that when I call the SConstruct from the C library directly from the command line, 'my_variabled' does not exists and scons raises an error:

```
scons: *** Import of non-existent variable ''my_variable''
```

Should I fix this using a try/except block in the called SConstruct as a switch to get the variable from scons or get the default, or are there more elegant solutions to this? Any suggestions on different approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're searching for the "`-u`" or the "`-U`" option. Please consult the [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) and have a pick for your needs.

Comment: Not really, since I want to be able to build the C library on its own without depending on SConstruct scripts in above directories. The value of 'my_variable' should then be filled in by some default value or if possible by the command line

Comment: But when you want to transport a variable from one SConstruct to another (as the title of the question and the actual description state) you *do* have a dependency between the two. I see a slight contradiction here...putting it differently, I'd probably skip the "requirement" that no top-level SConstructs should be called, and would be rewarded with instant relief from banging my head against this wall. ;)